# Combination of auto-renew and PayPal Pro (when paying w/ PayPal account) on membership pages results in "11502 invalid token" error message

Tags: 4.6.2, civicrm-home

**Update**
Per the Jira issue below, a fix has been submitted for the upcoming (October) 4.7 release, but not for the current 4.6.6. version.

---

Issue is regarding Recurring Contributions with Paypal Pro on Joomla. Same issue at the one summarized in the now deprecated forum: http://forum.civicrm.org/index.php/topic,35304.msg150570.html#msg150570

On CiviCRM 4.6.2 on Joomla 3.4.1

If this is identified as a feature request, what level of donation would enable the fix?

I submitted a bug here: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16850

Issue seems to be related to this: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-13362

I latest release log shows a few fixes related to the recurring payments but they do not address this issue: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16504?jql=fixVersion%20%3D%204.6.3%20AND%20project%20%3D%20CRM

Comment: How are folks handling this until the fix becomes available?  I have this error on a Drupal site (Drupal 7.39, CiviCRM 4.6.8).  We would disable the PayPal button until the fix is published, but [this forum thread](https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=34187.0) explains that doing so would violate the PayPal terms of use agreement.